# get ajax returned value in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok, this sounds super easy but still I have not found an answer that could help me.

I have this ajax callback inside a jquery function

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Im_general/obtenerDireccionAlmacen',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        idAlmacen: idAlmacen
    },
    success: function (returned) {
        var result = JSON.parse(returned);
        console.log(result.direccion);
        //here I set the returned string as input value
    }
});
```

I call a function from the database and expect a single string that I will append to a text input.
In the console output I can verify that the callback is working properly, as you can see in the image. But I still do not know how to get the value that is underlined.

[image: Console output]

Also, should I use succes or done for the callback?

Comment: try:  console.log((result.direccion)[0].domicile);

Comment: @techLove Thanks!! It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply an object.

```
console.log((result.direccion)[0].domicile);
```

Answer (score 1):

result.direccion[0].domicile would satisfy your need